# How to initialize member variable array with template type?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, declaration

How can I initialize an array, `s` of template type `T` in my constructor `Stack()`? This might be a really simple question, but I don't know much of c++. I get this error when compiling (GNU GCC):

> error: incompatible types in assignment of 'double*' to 'double [0]'

This is how I'm initializing the `Stack` object in my `main.cpp`:

```
Stack<double> stack;
```

And here is my `Stack.h` file (the implementation is included):

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T>

class Stack
{
    public:
        Stack();

    private:
        T s[];
        int N;
};

template <class T>

Stack<T>::Stack() {
    s = new T[5];
}
```

Comment: You should compile with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`, it'll tell you that `T s[];` is forbidden in ISO C++. You might want to use a pointer, but then, you have to follow the [rule of three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)/[five](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782757/rule-of-three-becomes-rule-of-five-with-c11). I suggest using a smart pointer like `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` instead.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't use `using namespace std;` in a header file.

Comment: Is this "stack" supposed to be fixed size? If so, use `template<class T, size_t N>` , your member declared as `T s[N];`, and lose the `N` member variable entirely. Use it as `Stack<double,5> var;` Again, assuming fixed-at-compile-time is what you seek.

Comment: You should really use a standard template library, such as `std::vector` or `std::list`. This is C++, not C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
//...
private:
    T s[];
```

to

```
//...
private:
    T *s;
```

This declaration

```
private:
    T s[];
```

is not C++ compliant. The size of the array shall be a constant expression. Moreover you declared an array but use it as a pointer in the constructor

```
s = new T[5];
```

Or use `std::vector` instead of the manually allocated array.

Comment: +1 That comes nearest to the originally given code. Though I think the most important mention in your answer is recommending usage of `std::vector<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

First, the size of array put on stack has to be known at compile time, so

```
T s[];
```

shoud read for instance

```
T s[10];
```

Second array of `T` is different type then `T*` return by `new`.

Solution:

```
class Stack
{
    public:
        Stack();
        ~Stack() { delete[] s_;}  // to avoid memory leak delete the array

    private:
        T* s;
        int N;
};

template <class T>
Stack<T>::Stack() {
    s = new T[10];
}
```

usage:

```
int main() {
    Stack<int> s;
    return 0;
}
```

---

Even better, make the size of array a template parameter:

```
template <class T, size_t N>
class Stack
{
    public:
        Stack();
        ~Stack() { delete[] s_;}  // to avoid memory leak delete the array

    private:
        T* s_;
        int N_;
};

template <class T, size_t N>
Stack<T,N>::Stack() : N_( N) {
    s_ = new T[N_];
}
```

usage:

```
int main() {
    Stack< int,10> s;
    return 0;
}
```

---

### Even better

Use templates, make standard container a template parameter:

```
template <class T, size_t N, template<class T, 
                                           class = std::allocator<T> > class C >
class Stack
{
    public:
        Stack();
        ~Stack() {}

    private:
        C<T> s_;
        int N_;
};

template <class T, size_t N, template<class T, 
                                           class = std::allocator<T> > class C >
Stack<T,N,C>::Stack() : N_( N) {
    s_.resize( N_);
}
```

usage:

```
int main() {
    Stack< int,10,std::vector > s;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One alternative is to give the array size as what is called a non-type template parameter (I'm assuming N is meant to represent the current stack size):

```
template <class T, int size>
class Stack
{
    public:
        Stack() : N(0) {}

    private:
        T s[size];
        int N;
};
```

You could use it as follows:

```
Stack<double, 5> myStack;
```